# Java Jersey - List to JSON conversion not working

Tags: java, json, list, jersey

While the service has no problem to convert TypeBean to JSON, I can't understand how to properly return and convert a List to JSON. This is the class representing the REST service.

```
@Path("/")
public class Service {
@GET
@Path("/types")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<TypeBean> getTypes() {
    List<TypeBean> types = new ArrayList<>();
    TypeBean tmp = new TypeBean();
    tmp.setId(0);
    tmp.setName("name");
    tmp.setDescription("description");
    types.add(tmp);
    return types;
}
@GET
@Path("/types/{typeid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TypeBean getType(@PathParam("typeid") int typeId) {
    return dsManager.getType(typeId);
}
}
```

This is the bean.

```
public class TypeBean implements Serializable {
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

When calling the service at `/types` I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/fitcity-web] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.isMapLikeType()Z
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildContainerSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:396)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:772)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:748)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:475)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:640)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:295)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:518)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The `pom.xml` content is this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>fitcity</groupId>
<artifactId>fitcity-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>fitcity-web</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the GenericEntity approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392413/jersey-return-a-list-of-strings

Comment: I've tried it now, but I get the same exception.

Comment: Well, that should do the trick. Which server are you using? Also, it may be worth to check that your dependencies are set correclty as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537287/jersey-and-jackson-maven-dependency-issues

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 7. For completeness I've added the pom.

Comment: Are you using explicitly the Jackson provider library? if not, try to remove it and give it a go.

Comment: IF you don't want to remove the jackson library then set jersey components version to 1.9.1 and add the jackson-core-asl dependency (jackson dependencies must be version 1.8.5).

Answer (score 0):

I've added to the pom the dependency to `jackson-core-asl`, version `1.8.5`, and it works.