# Jackson dependency version being overridden when doing maven build

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I had a perfectly working project. I was able to do a successful build and deployment. Yesterday as a part of development I had to add the following maven dependencies for Jackson jars in my project after which the `mvn clean install` started to fail.

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The error message that I get is

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project compass_app: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.XXXXX.services:compass_app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
>   depe dencies at org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.3 ->
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:j
>   r:1.9.13: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:pom:1.9.13 from/to m-all
>   (`http://XXXX/archives/all)`: Failed to transfer file:
>   `http://XXXX/archives/all/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.pom`.
>   Return code is: 500 , ReasonPhrase:Unable to find managed repository
>   configuration for id:npanXXXX-1.5.0-maestXXXX-33. -> [Help 1]

***My concern is why is the version 1.9.13 attempted for a download when I have not specified it anywhere in my project***

1. I have only one declaration of jackson jars in my pom file.
2. I have tried doing a mvn -X clean install > install.txt .

Following pieces of trace may be helpful.

```
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <artifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
  <attachedArtifacts default-value="${project.attachedArtifacts}"/>
  <createChecksum default-value="false">${createChecksum}</createChecksum>
  <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
  <packaging default-value="${project.packaging}"/>
  <pomFile default-value="${project.file}"/>
  <updateReleaseInfo default-value="false">${updateReleaseInfo}</updateReleaseInfo>
</configuration>
```

The Exception is.

```
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project compass_app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.XXXX.services:compass_app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.3 -> org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.XXXX.services:compass_app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.3 -> org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 22 more
```

Any assistance will be greatly helpful. thanks in advance.

References :- The following links have already been referred. 
1. [jersey and jackson maven dependency issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537287/jersey-and-jackson-maven-dependency-issues)
2. http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/xref/org/apache/maven/artifact/resolver/DebugResolutionListener.html  ( to understand the code and working of maven ) 
3. http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Answer (score 2):

> My concern is why is the version 1.9.13 attempted for a download when
>   I have not specified it anywhere in my project

Please use `mvn dependency:tree` (see: [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)) so that you will be able to track why this version is being loaded.

It is probably kind of [transitive dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).

Comment: thanks for your response. I had initially thought the same, and tried the mvn dependency:tree. but even then I am not able to see a complete dependency structure. The same error [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project compass_app.... comes up for the dependency tree command.

Comment: And could you try to phyiscally remove jars (at least jackson-related jars) from your local repository and try again so that they are redownloaded? The problem seems to be really strange.

Comment: Tried, but to no avail. Do you think this can be a problem with the repository connection, or some configuration setting specific to my maven settings?

Comment: @Hmm, you could create another, fresh installation of maven to eliminate the second option (configuration setting). The problem seems weird for me. This message: "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.5.3 -> org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13" suggests that mapper-asl:1.5.3 depends on core-asl:1.9.13 and tries to download it. But this is not true. As you can see here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.5.3/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3.pom mapper-asl:1.5.3 depends on core-asl:1.5.3! Do you use some custom maven repos or the central one?

Comment: Hi Piotr, Even I was thinking of creating a fresh installation now as a last resort. We are using custom maven repositories.

Comment: @Amal, could you paste somewhere the list of custom repositories that you are using. I have some suspiction about that.